# Xcode / Swift Scrollview Layout too wide

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm part of a team working on an app that uses auto-layout for the iPhone 6, but we just found out that we also need to support iPhone 4s and 5. Because the layout was designed for 6's larger screen, we decided to use ScrollViews.

I used this video as a tutorial of sorts:

[UIScrollView and Autolayout - Xcode 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI)

For the most part, it works. I can scroll up and down.

**The Problem:**

*Scrolling vertically works. But now I also have to scroll horizontally, which is not ideal / shouldn't happen.*

Even with the simulator set back to iPhone 6, anything with the scrollview gets widened to the point that the user has to scroll sideways.

Any suggestions?

**What I Tried:**

Some parts of the app does work without a hitch as far as my eye can see, but I've yet to apply a scrollview to those, so it's hard to tell if it's the scrollview's fault or something else at work. I did find this, though:

Non-working (scrollviews used - can scroll down, but width gets blown up):
[image]

Working (no scrollviews used - can't scroll down, but UI matches screen width):
[image]

I have no idea if that actually makes a difference. I tried to set the size to any/any as well, but that screws up with existing auto-layout constraints.

I also tried doing it programatically, but there's some known issues regarding the system returning the wrong screen size (which screws up everything even worse).

Comment: A valid question. I had a similar problem whenever I create ScrollView + Autolayout for different orientations. I've fixed them them but still don't know how, as they were done by trial and error. I'd be interested if anyone know the answer as well.

Comment: scroll views are surprisingly hard to work with. I had to google search UIScrollView tutorial to figure out how to implement them well

Comment: To clarify, you need only vertical scrolling for iPhone 4/5?

Comment: @rigdonmr, the tutorial video I used is linked up there. Strange, I've used it before on another project, and as far as I can remember, there weren't any issues like this - plus the video uses an iPhone for testing.

Comment: @srvv, yes. The rest of it should squeeze down to width - it does so without the scrollview.

Comment: Not entirely sure of the problem but are you saying what displays well for 6 size doesn't scale down to 4s/5 size? My guess is that the absolute size--points--are maintained and that'a why on 5, you have to scroll sideways?

Comment: @WoominJoshPark yes, that's what I'm saying, sorry if the question is too long. Anyway, srvv already answered below.

Comment: just for future reference, unlike other views, setting the view constraints' constant for top, right, bottom, left to 0 to the scroll view doesn't set the content size to that of the scroll view's bounds. the width of the embedded subview is the content size. as an experiment, you can set the content view's width to x3 of the scroll view's width and set the edge constraints' constant to 0. normally this would be a conflict, but not for scroll view subviews.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When working with ScrollView & AutoLayout you should put all content in a content view(UIView) and pin it to scroll view. (I am assuming this you did)

Now, If you want to disable horizontal scroll(like in TableView) then you will need to add a `equal width constraint` between `scroll view` & `content view`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This did it!

Comment: Here is some sample Swift 3 code for that: `scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0))`. The logic is that, by setting this constraint, you prevent the scrollView from having any content overflowing horizontally, and thus make it a vertically-only-scrolling scrollView. Conversely, you can swap both `width` attributes for `height` in that code snippet to make a horizontally-only-scrolling scrollView.

Comment: so ridiculous that you need a container for your container, but this did solve my issue thanks!